# How to use adjtimex

Tags: debian, ntp, ntpdate

I have a Debian machine that at the time of configuration will have access to NTP servers. But once configured and in use, it will not have access to NTP servers. What are the steps to ensure that the clock is correct at all times? (also after unexpected shutdowns)

As I understand, adjtimex is the right tool for the job. But it has a lot of options - so which one should I use?

**EDIT**

Possible steps?

1. `ntpdate-debian` // To update system clock from NTP servers.
2. `/sbin/hwclock --systohc` // To write clock and adjustment factors to /etc/adjtime.
3. Run the above two times with 24 hours between?
4. `adjtimexconfig` // Calculates drift between hwclock and system clock. Writes factor to /etc/default/adjtimex.
5. Create cronjob that calls `/sbin/hwclock --adjust` periodically.
6. Add `/sbin/hwclock --adjust && hwclock --hctosys --rtc=/dev/rtc0` to /etc/rc.local

Comment: I don't follow. How are you expecting to keep the clock correct without access to reference clocks?

Comment: I have access to reference clocks in the beginning of the configuration and can therefore set a correct clock. Then with help from hwclock and adjtimex, I can calculate the drift of the hardware clock and system clock and with the help of these same programs maintain a correct clock. Is this not right?

Comment: You're willing to assume that the hardware clock cannot gain or lose time? What do you do if on a restart you find out that your clock is ten minutes ahead? You jump back and possibly repeat times that previously ran?

Comment: Every time I call /sbin/hwclock --systohc, the systematic drift of the hardware clock is recalculated (gaining or losing time). That is why I am thinking, should I call it twice? Then calling /sbin/hwclock --adjust periodically and on startup would add or subtract seconds from the hardware clock based on the systematic drift. Is this not right?

Answer (score 0):

This approach won't work as the CPU clock can gain or lose time on any given day and will accumulating different drifts all the time. Without NTP, you will need a more reliable time reference, such as a rubidium time ref and a battery-backed clock for keeping time during power off or reboots. If you can get access to the sky, get a GPS with antenna and you can then run NTP without access to a network. This will give you the very best time...